# Call class method inside __init__

Tags: python, class

I want to call the method `connect()` in my `__init__()` method inside my class `db_connector()`.

Here's my code so far:

```
class db_connector(object):

   def connect(self, db_data):

       try:
           self.__con = psycopg2.connect(database = db_data['dbname'], user = db_data['user'])
           self.__cur = self.__con.cursor()
           logging.info(" Successfully connected to db.")
           return True

       except psycopg2.DatabaseError:
           logging.exception(" Error while connecting to db. Maybe check your login-data.")
           return False

   def __init__(self, db_data):

       self.__con = None
       self.__cur = None

       if self.__con:
           self.connect(db_data)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I've also tried switching positions from `__init__()` and `connect()`, so `__init__()` is over `connect()` - but in this case, he can't even find the method `connect()`.

Ideas?

Comment: The error indicates you misspelled the `__init__` method name.

Comment: Yes becouse he's trying to call object.__init__ .. But is isn't misspelled.

Comment: You didn't give us a *reproducable sample* here; we cannot see how you are *using* this class, nor did you include the full traceback.

Comment: And note that `self.__con` is always `None` in your code here, so `self.connect()` is never going to be called.

Comment: This advice is marvelous. I thought when I assign `None` to a variable, the variable has a value and will be called. So what do I assign to the variable if I need a "place holder" until the method is called? Thank you btw!!!

Comment: Why test for the value at all here? You *know* `self.__con` is always going to be `None` (a valid 'placeholder' value), so just call `self.connect()` without testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling another method from your `__init__` is fine and not the cause of your problems here. Instead, you somehow misspelled the `__init__` method, and creating an instance ends up calling `object.__init__` instead.

Double-check the spelling of the method, and make sure it is indented correctly to be part of the `db_connector` class definition.